# Woocommerce add dismiss button to cart notifications

Tags: woocommerce, checkout

Is it possible to add a dismiss (x) button to notifications during the checkout page. For example if a client enters an incorrect coupon code, the following markup is added.

```
<ul class="woocommerce-error" role="alert">
    <li>Coupon "123" does not exist!</li>
</ul>
```

However the customer cannot dismiss this message.

Haven't tried anything other than Googling for the answer.

Comment: It's possible, but this would require an overwriting of the notices templates, which can be found here: `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/notices`. You can add a dismiss button inside the overwritten template.

Answer (score 0):

I found some code online that worked for me, the issue was the element I was trying to target didn't exist. So the code uses a much broader method to target the notices.

```
document.addEventListener( "click", someListener );

function someListener(event){
    var element = event.target;
    if(element.classList.contains("woocommerce-error")){
      element.classList.add('dismissed');

    }
}
```

This successfully adds the class to the element.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).